# git ls-tree db/*.rb not working

Tags: git

I am looking at the [man page for git ls-tree](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-ls-tree) . It has an option for path.

I have a directory called db and in that directory I have a few .rb files.

Then why my command is failing

```
git ls-tree db/*.rb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the [actual man page is here](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-tree.html). That is the page for the latest Git version.

Second, that official man page says:

> Lists the contents of a given tree object, like what "`/bin/ls -a`" does in the current working directory.
>   Note that:
>
> - the behaviour is slightly different from that of "`/bin/ls`" in that the paths denote just a list of patterns to match, e.g. so specifying directory name (without `-r`) will behave differently, and order of the arguments does not matter.
> - the behaviour is similar to that of "`/bin/ls`" in that the paths is taken as relative to the current working directory.
>     E.g. when you are in a directory sub that has a directory dir, you can run **`git ls-tree -r HEAD dir`** to list the contents of the tree (that is `sub/dir` in `HEAD`).
>     You don't want to give a tree that is not at the root level (e.g. `git ls-tree -r HEAD:sub dir`) in this case, as that would result in asking for `sub/sub/dir` in the `HEAD` commit. However, the current working directory can be ignored by passing `--full-tree` option.

In your case:

```
git ls-tree HEAD db/*.rb
```

might work better.

Comment: Note: depending on what you want to do, `git ls-files' might be more appropriate (http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-files.html)